# PHPExcel date getting subtracted on some rows

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am  struggling with this error for a couple of hours. I trying to upload a xlsx file which contain dates. In that some of the dates are calculated based on other dates .

The issue which I am getting on this is some of the date  fields it is subtracting one day automatically while uploading . But in the xlsx sheet it is displaying properly.

Any idea what is wrong with the my code . Is this one related to my code or could be  xlsx problem?

This is the code to get the date from the excel

```
    PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::toFormattedString($objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(9,$row)-
>getCalculatedValue(), "M/D/YYYY");
```

Comment: How your dates are stored in the xlsx file ? And what are the corresponding cells types ?

Comment: Without knowing the details of the calculations, it's almost impossible to say

Comment: the dates are stored in dd/mm/yyyy format.

Comment: @MarkBaker This is one of the formula used in the cell =IF(D8="","",WORKDAY(D8,-12))

Comment: The dates should not be stored in any format if they're actual dates, they should be a float with a numberformat mask to render any formatting as human-readable

Comment: So is the problem with the value stored in cell D8? Or is it with the WORKDAY calculation?

Comment: @MarkBaker Not on entire D8 column values . But on some dates on that column.

Comment: In that case, I need to know which ones are causing the problem... and to narrow down whether the discrepancy is in the WORKDAY function, or in the conversion of the float calculated by WORKDAY to a human-readable date format - can you create a small sample spreadsheet that demonstrates the problem and upload it to the codeplex site

Comment: @MarkBaker https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/workitem/20426 .

Answer (score 0):

Without more code it is hard to guess where the date is changed. Depending on how the date is handled, could it be that it is a timezone issue?